# "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined" using Ionic2 InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm using [`InAppBrowser`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inappbrowser/) from [`ionic-native`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/) to open an system browser window and watch for a particular callback URL to be loaded. Here's a snippet of my code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserEvent } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({/* ... properties ... */})
export class MyPage {

    /* ... constructor, etc. ... */

    // function triggered by button click on the page
    register() {
        let url = 'https://example.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=29D20X';
        let browser: InAppBrowser = new InAppBrowser(url, '_system');
        browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((ev: InAppBrowserEvent) => { // line 23
            if (0 === ev.url.indexOf('http://localhost:8100/callback')) {
                console.log(ev.url);
                browser.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As soon as the `register()` function is triggered, the browser window opens with the expected page, but meanwhile on the page from which it was opened, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at Observable._subscribe (inappbrowser.js:79)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:56)
    at MyPage.register (my-page.ts:23)
```

There's more after that in the stack trace, but it's pretty clear that the problem is in the `ionic-native` wrapper for `inappbrowser`.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something? Here's my system info, and I'm testing this in a browser using `ionic serve`.

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.5
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: 1.8.2
ios-sim version: 5.0.3
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v7.0.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!!!

The problem was in the parameters being passed to the `new InAppBrowser()` function.

This **works**:

```js
let browser = new InAppBrowser(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

This does **NOT** work:

```js
let browser = new InAppBrowser(url, '_system');
```

I was following [this documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inappbrowser/) and after a lot of googling and reading through random threads about inappbrowser, I finally found the solution. Essentially, both of these will open a browser window. However, the incorrect method will not allow you to attach an event listener to any of the browser events, e.g. loadstart.